# Trying to Call an Update method in Button Click event

Tags: asp.net, methods, datagridview, tableadapter

I am looping 2 Datagrids and getting the IndividualID's (PrimaryKeys) of the person(s) that are selected. I have debugged this and the loops are working fine. Howver when I call my Update Method from my Table Adapter, nothing seems to happen. It does not update. Here is my code. Not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
    protected void imgbtnReassgin_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{




    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvAdminCustomer.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkitemSelectorCustomers");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {


            int oIndividualID  = Convert.ToInt32((gvAdminCustomer.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value));
          //  GlobalVar.oIndividualID = oIndividualID;


            foreach (GridViewRow r in gvReassignCustomers.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkitemSelectorAllManagersandSalesman");
                if (chkBox != null && chkBox.Checked)
                {

                    int oNewParentID = Convert.ToInt32((gvReassignCustomers.DataKeys[r.RowIndex].Value));


                    individualTableAdapter ind = new individualTableAdapter();

                    //Individual ind = new Individual();
                    ind.reassign_Individual(oIndividualID, oNewParentID);

                }

            }
            gvAdminCustomer.DataBind();


        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it updating the database record and not reflecting on the grid? If that is the case, then it looks like it is just rebinding the grid with the datasource it used prior to the loop. You'll need to refresh your dataset and then rebind:

```
gvAdminCustomer.DataSource = YourDataSource;    
gvAdminCustomer.DataBind();
```

Good Luck!

Comment: its not updating the database at all. But I will try this approach.